# How to add an existing database file into my windows phone 7 app and read data from it?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to add a existing database file say (ex:- x.sdf) and dump the data present in the database file into phone's local database?

I want do this when the end user is installing the app itself.

Comment: Are you going to need to update the database or will the data be readonly?

Comment: i want to read/write on the database(perform operations on it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Application Deployment" part of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) article; there you'll see how you can deploy a readonly database with your application, and what will you need to do in order to make it writable once it is deployed!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the preloaded DB then you can Add a sqlCe DB in your application and populate the db with your seed Data.
 then you can copy the DB file to your ISO Store while your Constructor of DBContext is invoked.

```
public Moviadb1DataContext (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!iso.FileExists("Moviadb1.sdf"))
        {
            MoveReferenceDatabase();
        }

        if (!DatabaseExists())
            CreateDatabase();
    }

    public static void MoveReferenceDatabase()
    {
        // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
        IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // Create a stream for the file in the installation folder.
        using (Stream input = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Moviadb1.sdf", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
        {
            // Create a stream for the new file in isolated storage.

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream output = iso.CreateFile("Moviadb1.sdf"))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the file from the installation folder to isolated storage. 
                while ((bytesRead = input.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    output.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```