# Can I include a database in the XAP, or should I create the database on initial load, for a Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows Phone 7.1 application that currently uses data from text files. At this point I'd like to see how well my queries perform using a database.

This is the first application where no data will be written by the user, instead a number of pre-defined queries will pull the data they request.

In the past I've created the database when the application started for the first time. In this case, since I have the data they'll need, I wonder if I can just create the database (WP7.1, so I'm going to use SQL Server Compact Edition) and include it in the XAP.

I've seen [How to add an existing database file into my windows phone 7 app and read data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922649/11912), which gets me to [How to: Deploy a Reference Database with a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286411%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), that has an important note that:

> Microsoft SQL Server Compact (SQL CE) databases that have been created on the desktop may work with a Windows Phone application, but are not officially supported.

Should I just include data files that will be loaded into a database when the application is loaded, like I've done for my CRUD applications, or can I safely include a database I've created during development?

Comment: I have never heard on any Latin langauge developer having issues with including a database.

Comment: @ErikEJ, I'm sorry, I don't think I get your comment.

Comment: As described in my blog post, you can emebed a database, also for read/write, and have only heard of developers having issues if they created the database on a non-latin language desktop OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing to dig into it, I found Jerry Nixon's series on Mango databases, in particular [Mango Sample: Database Part 2:2](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-database-part-22.html).

I found he actually laid out the steps a little more completely.

> Step 1: Create the Database
>
> Step 2: Construct your Schema and Default Data
>
> Step 3: Include the Database in your Project
>
> Step 4: Generate your Entities with SqlMetal
>
> Step 5: Clean up the Data Context

The last step includes information about moving the database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this previous question here on Stackoverflow. This has been answered already here

[Windows Phone 7 databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583475/windows-phone-7-databases)

Summarizing that answer, yes you can included pre populated DB file with your application, but it is readonly, look at these blog posts it clearly explains how to achieve this -

http://blog.arsanth.com/?p=343

http://erikej.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/windows-phone-local-database-tip.html

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised I didn't find that question via Google or SO's search; the title is pretty lacking :) I had looked at Erik's blog a couple of times (searches and other SO questions kept bringing me over there), and while I hadn't seen that one, it's not quite what I was hoping for. He actually says in the last paragraph that he presents an 'overview' of the options.